# this в методе при присвоении

Tags: javascript

Почему во втором варианте, в котором мы присваиваем и сразу вызываем метод, 
 this равно window?

```
let user = {
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
};

user.sayBye = user.sayHi;
user.sayBye(); // this = user



let user1 = {
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this) 
  }
};

(user1.sayBye = user1.sayHi)(); // this = window
```

Comment: Был недавно такой вопрос. Сводится всё к тому, что во втором случае вызывается результат присваивания, которым является сама функция, без привязки к объекту `user1`. Выходит то же самое, что и в случае `let func = user1.sayHi; func();`

Comment: Спасибо, понятно